# Reading lines of a file and comparing

Tags: file, text, compare

I'm trying to implement some code to compare the lines from two text files and determine if they're equal or different. However, my logic doesn't seem to work on the while statement because I get an error when there's an extra line in one of the text files. Any ideas how I can change this to take into account extra lines?

```
try {
            final File textfile1 = new File("Text1.txt");
            final File textfile2 = new File("Text2.txt");
            Scanner text1 = new Scanner(textfile1);
            Scanner text2 = new Scanner(textfile2);

            while (text1.hasNext() || text2.hasNext())

            {
                line1 = text1.nextLine();
                line2 = text2.nextLine();

                if (line1.equals(line2))
                    System.out.println("The lines are equal");
                else
                    System.out.println("\"" + line1 + "\" does not equal \"" + line2 + "\"");

            }

            text1.close();
            text2.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
```

Comment: thats because its trying to comapre it with undefined or null value

Comment: What error are you getting? Might be empty or null error put check condition for that too.

Answer (score 1):

Well the crux of it is the evaluation `while (text1.hasNext() || text2.hasNext())` which just means one of the two needs to not be at then end of the file but then   making the call for `nextLine` on both.  Issue there again is one of the two may have reached the end.

You could switch to use `&&` instead of `||` to ensure neither of the two are at the end, or make an evaluation on each file before seeking.

For example...

```
while (text1.hasNext() || text2.hasNext()) {
    line1 = null; line2 = null;
    if (text1.hasNext()) line1 = text1.nextLine();
    if (text2.hasNext()) line2 = text2.nextLine();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code reads both texts, whether they have more content or not.
You should only read the texts if they both have content, and then check whether one is longer than the other.

```
while (text1.hasNext() && text2.hasNext()){
    line1 = text1.nextLine();
    line2 = text2.nextLine();

    if (line1.equals(line2))
        System.out.println("The lines are equal");
    else
        System.out.println("\"" + line1 + "\" does not equal \"" + line2 + "\"");
}

if (text1.hasNext())
    System.out.println("text 1 has more lines");
if (text2.hasNext())
    System.out.println("text 2 has more lines");
```

Comment: This would be more helpful to future users if you add some text explaining what your code does and how it solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in the logic to run while loop. Run while loop for true and read lines in loop, then compare lines text.

```
try {
    final File textfile1 = new File("Text1.txt");
    final File textfile2 = new File("Text2.txt");
    Scanner text1 = new Scanner(textfile1);
    Scanner text2 = new Scanner(textfile2);
    bool flag = true;

    while (flag)
    {
         if(!text1.eof() || !text2.eof() 
         {
            line1 = text1.nextLine();
            line2 = text2.nextLine();

            if (line1.equals(line2))
               System.out.println("The lines are equal");
            else
               System.out.println("\"" + line1 + "\" does not equal \"" + line2 + "\"");
         } else { 
            flag = false;
         }
    }

    text1.close();
    text2.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
}
```